# Getting Error: did you install mysqlclient? even though mysqlclient is installed on MacOS when trying to access the database in django

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am using MacOS 10.13.1 and python version 3.7.2.
I used `pip3 install mysqlclient` to install mysqlclient and it was successful:

```sh
MacBook-Air:~ user$ pip3 install mysqlclient
```

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/9b/5db9a03e2088a87c26e3e4d4c7f7e8f4c2dbae610f9521cdfac15755a795/mysqlclient-1.4.5.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for mysqlclient: filename=mysqlclient-1.4.5-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl size=56101 sha256=3c1ab2eed45ecf064e60ceda15f2d85f4b01367e7c7e6ed887f483732b9d5e8c
  Stored in directory: /Users/user/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/26/51/0c/3b9ab7013c539c744cddb55989ef494779fa08e8b273ab5ddf
Successfully built mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Successfully installed mysqlclient-1.4.5
```

pip3 list confirms that version 1.4.5 of mysqlclient has been installed.

However, when running `python3 manage.py makemigrations` in the directory containing my project, this error comes up:

```sh
MacBook-Air:averages user$ python3 manage.py shell
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'averages_db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
    }
}
```

I have looked at other posts with similar problems but I have found nothing of use. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Alasdair Yes, mysqlclient is listed and I checked pip3 is using the correct version of python (3.7)

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution? I have run into the same issue and do not know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using Python3.7 when executing `pip3`:

`pip3 --version`

My output (debian) is:

```
pip 19.2.3 from /home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

My version of `pip3` is using Python3.5.

The solution to install it with python3.7 would be to execute:

`python3.7 -m pip install mysqlclient`

If that is the case, you might want to use the Python tool virtual environment [link](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/).

Comment: pip3 --version outputs that it is using Python 3.7, so this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error myself and for me the problem was that the pip install was placing my files into my /usr/local/mysql/lib folder.  When trying to use it with python it is searching for the libraries in /usr/local/lib instead.  Just copy pasting the files from my /usr/local/mysql/lib into /usr/local/lib solved the issue for me.

Note Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib near the start of the error message.  I copy pasted that library and then the same error came up but with a different library.  Copy pasted again twice more with libssl.1.1.dylib and then libcrypto.1.1.dylib.  After putting all three of the mentioned libraries into /usr/local/lib, it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

You need run this command:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

In your virtual environment. [Link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Comment: I have already done that and it is installed but I am having the issue regardless.